# show error message when the course is already register in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want this code to show me a error message when student already register a course

```
 $reds = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT count(*) FROM `course` " );
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($reds);
    $num = $row[0];

echo $num>0 ; die();
   var_dump($num) ;die();
    if ($num>0){
   // echo "record already exits";
}

else {


    $sd = "INSERT INTO `users_course`(users_id,course_id) VALUES ( ' {$_SESSION['users_id']}', '$course_id')";
    $r = mysqli_query($db, $sd);
        if ($r) {

        $m = ' register';
        header('location: registercourse.php'); //redirect to index page after inserting
```

Comment: please provide the proper question, enough explanation is required in order to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like below:-

```
<?php
    session_start(); //start session to use session variable
    $user_id = $_SESSION['users_id'];
    $reds = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `users_course` WHERE users_id = $user_id AND course_id= $course_id " );

    if (mysqli_num_rows($reds)>0){
        echo "record already exits";exit;
}else {
    $sd = "INSERT INTO `users_course`(users_id,course_id) VALUES ( $user_id, $course_id)";
    $r = mysqli_query($db, $sd);
    if ($r) {
        $m = ' register';
        header('location: registercourse.php'); //redirect to index page after inserting
    }else{
        echo "error:-".mysqli_error($db);
    }
}
```

***Note:-*** May be above code worked for you currently, but it is wide open for SQL Injection, so try to read `prepared statements` and use them.

[mysqli.prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

***So check this for an example:-***

```
<?php
    session_start(); //start session to use session variable
    $user_id = $_SESSION['users_id'];
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT * FROM `users_course` WHERE users_id = ? AND course_id= ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $user_id, $course_id);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* store result */
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)>0){
        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        echo "record already exits";exit;
    }else{
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db,"INSERT INTO `users_course`(users_id,course_id) VALUES (?, ?)";
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $user_id, $course_id);
        if ( mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            $m = ' register';
            header('location: registercourse.php'); //redirect to index page after inserting
        }else{
            echo "error:-".mysqli_error($db);
        }
    }

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: thank you  it work perfectly

Comment: @dannycool  glad to help you. Please read my note section carefully and try the second solution once.Thanks

Comment: kindly tell me why we need to use mysqli_prepare

Comment: prevent your code from `SQL INJECTION`. search `SQL INJECTION` on google and read about it

Comment: i read it thank you

Comment: I tried prepaid statement code it give me an error

Comment: @dannycool  please ask a new question with your code effort as well as error statement. You will get answer for-sure

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass `users_id` in your query to check if a particular student (user id) has registered for the course or not.

```
$reds = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT count(*) FROM `users_course` where users_id = `".$_SESSION['users_id']."` and course_id='".$course_id."'" );
```

Because with current SELECT query, you are checking only if there is any course present in the course table. So as there would be some rows, it is giving your error message that course is already there.

Hope this is the clear explaination for you.

Comment: Would be better if you would use prepared statements and bind variables.

Comment: thank you very very much

Comment: Happy to help @dannycool

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the structure of your database but i think you have to change this query 'SELECT count(*) FROM `course` '
to "SELECT count(*) FROM `users_course` WHERE course_id = '{$_SESSION['users_id']}' AND user_id = '$course_id'"